# how can we mock each line in sping boot for testing

Tags: junit, mockito, junit4, spring-test

we are working in a project where our lead asked to mock every object in every line and see if every line of code is working fine and
the first line is shiftstaffentity object creation
the second line is json object creation

this is the third line
if(!jobj.isnull(shiftstaffentity))

how do we test this method? in junit and mockito

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly test lines of code in Java. It is only possible to test methods. Depending on the design of your test and classes/methods your test will cover every line of code.

If your lead gives you so detailed requirements for your tests please ask them to explain to you how you can do it. It is their responsibility to enable you to do the work that they assign to you. They get paid for it and your company earns money from the work you're doing while the people here on Stack Overflow are helping in their free time.